# Jquery setInterval() not working

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to create a kind of slideshow.

The problem:

```
function slides(x) {
      $("#irack").stop().animate({"left": x}, 20);
 };
setInterval(slides(-30),300);
```

This code only moves the div to the left 1 time.

Why doesn't it move the div every 300ms ?

Comment: Off-topic: `setInterval` can cause issues if it runs for long durations. It's generally advisable to use recursive `setTimeout` calls rather than `setInterval`.

Comment: It won't run too much time. As I said in another comment, I'm just using setInterval to scroll a div while the mouse is held down, after that I clear the interval.

Comment: `setInterval` is not a jQuery function.  It is a builtin JavaScript function.

Comment: @mareoraft Yeah, 7 years later now I know that :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to wrap the code to run at intervals in a function:

```
function slides(x) {
      $("#irack").stop().animate({"left": x}, 20);
};
setInterval(function() {
    slides(-30);
}, 300);
```

<s>Did you *really* mean [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval)? That will keep happening, every 300ms or so. If you want it just to happen once, use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.setTimeout) instead.</s>

**Update**: If you want to cancel the interval later, you'll need to save the handle to a variable:

```
// Somewhere appropriate, have a variable for the handle
var handle = 0; // 0 = not running

...

// Starting:
handle = setInterval(...);

...

// Stopping:
if (handle != 0) {
    clearInterval(handle);
}
handle = 0;
```

Note the use of `0` for the handle when it's not set. `0` is an invalid return value from `setInterval`, so you can rely on it. (You can use `undefined` or `null` if you like as well, just be sure to check for them.)

Comment: No, I want setInterval because I will execute the setInterval function on MouseDown and cancel it in MouseOut :D

Comment: @Cristy: Ah, then you'll need the handle of the interval. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. So why does the slides() method need to be wrapped in another function?

Comment: @loeschg: Because we need to pass the argument to it (`-30`). If you know you're on an ECMAScript5 environment, you could use [`Function#bind`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5) like this: `setInterval(slides.bind(undefined, -30), 300);` But you can't count on ECMAScript5 features yet (unless you include a shim, since `bind` is one of the things shims can do).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Clearly I have some stuff to learn :). Not really sure what ECMAScript5 or "shims" are. I can do some research on my own. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @loeschg: You're welcome! ECMAScript5 (ES5) is the latest version of "JavaScript": The official name of the standard language is ECMAScript, and the 5th edition specification was released just two years ago or so; [here's a link to an HTML version of it](http://es5.github.com). A "shim" (in this context) is something that provides standard functionality on browsers that don't yet support it natively. Some of the new things in ES5 can be supplied even on 3rd edition engines (there was no 4th edition), others can't be. Search for "es5 shim" and you'll find several. Best,

Answer (score 5):

In you call to setInterval the slides method is being called inline change the call to as below:

```
setInterval(function(){slides(-30);},300);
```

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks! Anyone know why this needs to be done?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're calling the function you're passing to setInterval

You'll need to wrap the function in an anonymous function to pass a parameter as part of the interval.

```
function slides(x) {
      $("#irack").stop().animate({"left": x}, 20);
 };
setInterval(function(){slides(-30)},300);
```

Note how the `slides(-30)` is now wrapped in an anon function.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I've found the problem :D

```
$("#irack").stop().animate({"left": x}, 20);
```

The problem is that "x" is a constant, and it changes the "left" to x and keeps it that way.

I should do this way:

```
x=$("#irack").offset().left+x;
$("#irack").stop().animate({"left": x}, 20);
```

And thanks a lot for pointing that "wrapping" stuff :D.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer is:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#irack").stop().animate({"left": -30}, 20)
},300);
```