# how to setInterval in react component constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to setInterval when main component.
i tried setting it in constructor like

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.fetchUserInfo();
    this.props.fetchProducts();
    setInterval(console.log('1'), 1000);
  }
```

or inside `componentDidMount`

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    setInterval(console.log('1'), 1000);
  };
```

but it always logs '1' once. How to launch interval properly?

Comment: Another one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4555656/218196 .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setInterval(console.log('1'), 1000);` **calls** `console.log('1')` and passes its return value into `setInterval`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value to `foo`.

You want to pass a function reference to it:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('1');
}, 1000);
```

Or if you need `this` to be the same inside that function and are not yet using ES2015 syntax:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('1');
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

`Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, calls the original using the `this` value you give it.

Or if you are using ES2015 syntax

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log('1');
}, 1000);
```

That will close over the `this` where it's created, no need for `bind`.

Comment: oh thanks for quick answer, just forgot how to use that.